# Parallelization with Rborist

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, parallel-processing

I have a large n (>1,000,000) dataset with a small number of features to estimate (regression) random forest and have been looking to implement Rborist (in R). I'd like to parallelize my work, but am not finding much guidance on how that would be done. I have 16 processors to use on the machine where it's running. When I use doParallel with the randomForest package, for example, the command:

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(32, 16), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% randomForest(x, y, nodesize = 25, ntree=ntree)
```

It launches 16 R processes, and works slowly as randomForest does, but works.

The analogous command for Rborist:

```
rb <- foreach(ntree=rep(32, 16), .combine=combine, .packages='Rborist') %dopar% Rborist(x, y, minNode = 25, ntree=ntree)
```

Throws the error:

> error calling combine function:
>
> Warning message: In mclapply(argsList, FUN, mc.preschedule =
>   preschedule, mc.set.seed = set.seed,  :   all scheduled cores
>   encountered errors in user code

Does anyone know how to parallelize with Rborist? It does not appear to be happening under the hood as it's only using 1 cpu when I run:

```
rb <- Rborist(x, y, minNode = 25, ntree = 512)
```

Comment: Does it work single threaded with Rborist? Otherwise, not an answer really, but I use the h2o implementaiton of random forest, h2o.randomForest when doing big analysis. Find it easier than to use foreach.

Comment: Yes, the single-threaded version works. At least in my setting it is indeed much faster than vanilla randomForest, though it does require much more RAM, and the prediction accuracy has been lower ( I wonder if this is due to difference is stopping criteria between randomForest and Rborist's mininfo default).

Answer (score 1):

Rborist runs in parallel by itself. It uses all my threads on my machine (win 10 64bit). But then I didn't load doParallel / foreach first.

Same goes for the ranger package, but in ranger you can set the number of threads to use.

Speedy implementations of a rf are of the top of my head:

- Rborist (large n, low p)
- ranger (handles large p, modest n)
- random forest.ddr (haven't tested)
- distributed random forest in H2O. very fast, but makes use of
  stopping criteria.

Comment: Hm, do you think it could be a Mac/PC thing? When I run it without doParallel loaded it's still only using 1 cpu according to activity monitor.

Comment: it shouldn't be but you never know. compilation via gcc and uses rcpp. You could try the version on github or file an issue on the github page if it persists.

Comment: @phiver How would you compare H2o vs rborist  and H2o vs ranger for speed with large features and large n   .. trying to find a c++ random forest that can be faster than then h2o version  and still handle those features.

Comment: @phiver only asking your informal opinion. thank you!

Comment: @physicist, on a single machine / AWS instance either rborist or ranger would do. I prefer ranger, because it is also used in other packages like Boruta. Support for both is still ongoing, which is important as well. If you have time you can run speed comparisons. Code for this is available [here](https://github.com/szilard/benchm-ml/tree/master/z-other-tools). I like H20 for the support they have and all the other functionalities. Speed on my machine between h2o and ranger is comparable. I don't use clusters much for my work :-). But some things do depend on what you consider large n / p.

Answer (score 0):

Rborist currently uses all available cores.  Would it be useful to offer a way to tune this?

Have you tried the latest version on CRAN, 0.1-3?  This contains a change to the default minimum node size for regression, improving accuracy in some cases.

We've been making some strides toward improving performance with modest (as opposed to small) predictor count.  This should also be reflected by changes in the latest release.

Large *running* memory footprint is probably a consequence of the breadth-first splitting approach.  One way to conserve memory is to carve the problem into chunks, but we haven't gotten there yet.

Large *final* memory size is chiefly due to caching leaf information for subsequent use by other packages or for quantile regression.  Perhaps we should add a "noLeaf" option for users who are not interested in either of those options.

Comment: Thanks--I'm running version 0.1-3. It's using all available processors when I run it on Linux, but only 1 of 8 possible processors when running on OS X with identical code.

Comment: This may be related to the state of OpenMP support on your OS X distribution.  It sounds similar to reports from users of other packages.   Do you observe multi-core occupancy with other any R packages built using OpenMP?